# Check for key word through Linq in List

Tags: linq, list, count

I have a List through which I need to check if an item of the list (DescVal) contains and * and if so, return a false. I guess I can even have it return the records that have an * and then do a count and if the count is 0 then I know it was false but if it can return false to begin with, that would be great.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```
if (list.Any(o => o.SomeString.Contains("*")))
```

Comment: My list name is data1, Are Any, Something keywords?